# Can we remove the "multiple closed questions" automatic system flag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, moderator-tools

For a while, we've had a "multiple closed questions" flag that is cast automatically by the system when at least three questions by a single user have been closed. That originally worked to help identify problematic askers so that we could guide them, message them, or otherwise handle them.

Since question bans were implemented on several sites, a robust review system put into place, and warnings are now given to users asking repeated bad questions, these flags no longer seem to have any purpose. On Stack Overflow, they are pure busywork and never require any moderator intervention.

As a result of the recent changes in the way that the close votes queue is sorted, we are now seeing dozens if not over a hundred of these flags a day. They are a waste of time on Stack Overflow, and potentially elsewhere, so I would like to request that they be deactivated on that site (and wherever else moderators don't want them anymore).

Comment: Disabling them on Stack Overflow makes sense, but I think it's too early to remove them across the board. Most sites don't have question bans or quite the same robust review experience that SO enjoys.

Comment: @AnnaLear I've rarely acted on these, I find most of them to be noise. I mod on small sites where we tend to spot problem users manually anyway. Maybe these flags are useful on medium-sized sites. Do you have statistics on declined “multiple closed questions” flags (I always decline Community's flags when they're noise), or are those just not recorded at all?

Comment: @AnnaLear - I had asked Shog9 about this, and he seemed to think that the new quality warnings might be enough even on the smaller sites. I didn't know if this would just apply to Stack Overflow, but he thought posting it here was worthwhile.

Comment: @Gilles We can pull that data, but my money is on it being useless. I bet most mods dismiss Community flags as helpful since it's faster regardless of whether they actually were useful or not.

Comment: @Brad Wouldn't be the first time Shog and I disagreed on a thing. :) That said, I'd likely defer to his opinion on this since I haven't had a chance to closely look at the network-wide data on these features recently.

Comment: I definitely agree with this on high-volume sites; my experience matches Brad's here. Almost every single time, the right thing has already happened to the person in question, or there's some fluke, and nothing needs to be done. I have almost zero experience with low-volume sites, so... can't offer anything useful there.

Comment: @AnnaLear Guilty as charged. It is true though that these flags almost never solicit any action.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After a bit of research and discussion, it seems that these flags are just noise.

We've updated the threshold for triggering this flag everywhere, since the question ban is enabled network-wide now. The flag still exists but it will be essentially impossible to generate it.

<strike>As a result, we've raised the threshold for triggering this flag on the handful of sites with the question ban enabled, including Stack Overflow.</strike>

Comment: Not even a week in and you've already found a *new* way to handle flags - by reprogramming them completely.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I don't mess around. :)

Comment: Could we get this on other sites now that the question ban is more universal?

Comment: @jonsca Done everywhere on the network. It will be pretty much impossible to raise these flags.

Comment: @bluefeet Thanks so much!!